# Issues with tax

Tags: commerce

I have enabled **Commerce Tax**. Under Home >  Administration > Commerce > Configuration > Tax I selected 'European Union VAT' and enabled 'Display taxes of this type inclusive in product price'. In other words: tax inclusive.
Then I installed **Commerce Product Tax**. As per instructions on https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_tax I have created the tax rule in each product variation type. For food items 9% and for non-food items 21%.

You can set a variation in each product. I set the price including the tax.

If you click on a product the price is shown, I assume including the tax. If you add an item to the basket the tax is added again. Also, the subtotal and total are the same amounts, while the tax amount is shown. That is weird.

So, my question is: how to show the price including tax in the cart. Or excluding tax but with a correct calculation.

Feedback is appreciated and with kind regards,
TheStingPilot

Comment: "If you click on a product the price is shown, I assume including the tax. " What do you mean? You set the price yourself, and you set the tax rate, so you know whether the price includes tax or not...

Comment: You will find all the products under **Home  > Administration > Commerce**. Pick a product click **Edit** and go to Variations. Click **Edit** again and you see the price. I assume that price includes the VAT.

Or... as the module is called **Commerce Product Tax** the tax is always added and the price by the product should always exclude the VAT.